# Number Of Ways to generate Codes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Using the English only `A-Z` alphabet and numeric `0−9`, I need to calculate how many combinations will be possible to get when we take a test for 5 digits code.

Code Has `3 Alphabet` and `2 Numeric` Digits.

Comment: Is known which exact digits of the code are alphabetical and which are numeric? If this is the case it is quiet simple to calculate.

Comment: No infomration about the position is given

Comment: Am I missing something with my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\frac{5!}{2!*3!}$ ways of arranging the numbers and letters, there are $26^3$ ways to pick the three letters, and there are $10^2$ ways to pick the numbers. Multiply all those results to get an answer.